# Вернуть R.java Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

Здравствуйте, как вернуть стёртый `R.java`?

Answer (score 2):

Project -> Clean. Но если в проекте есть ошибки, файл не создастся.

Comment: я делал не помогло , у меня стерся R.java и весь проект красный в ошибках

Comment: Сначала нужно полностью избавиться от ошибок. В моём случае помогло полное закомментирование некоторых java файлов

Comment: Обычно проблемы в xml файлах. Их в первую очередь надо на ошибки проверить.

Comment: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: ошибак нету в xml